# Generate multiple Gridviews with properties of another Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I Have one gridview declared in ASP something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_Sample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="false" CssClass="tabela" style="margin: 0 auto;"
                UseAccessibleHeader="true" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col1 column">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Nome
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col1 column" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <p><asp:Label ID="lbl_micro" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Descricao") %>' /></p>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Curso" HeaderStyle-CssClass="col2 column">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Curso
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col2 column" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="link_micro" runat="server" Text='<%# "<span>"+ Eval("id") + "</span>" %>' NavigateUrl='<%# returnRawUrl() + "&id=" + Eval("id") %>' CssClass="linkBlock button-cursos" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>                        
        </asp:GridView>
```

In code behind I want generate multiple Gridviews with all the properties of GV_Sample, and just change the DataSource:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.Count; i++)
{
     GridView gvr = GV_Sample;
     gvr.id="myGV_"+i;
     SqlDosCursos.SelectParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = array[i];
     gvr.DataSourceID = "SqlDosCursos";
     gvr.DataBind();
     myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gvr);
}
```

The problem is only the last cycle of my for insert the GridView in the placeholder, all the other's who should be inserted are not there. 
How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: GridView gvr = GV_Sample; <--- that code is not generating grid views, its only assigning a reference to GV_Sample grid view.

Comment: How can i generate gridview with reference to GV_Sample?

Comment: when you say generate new instance you use the "new" keyword, what you're doing is only reference assignment.  I don't what you're trying to achieve but it's better if you do it using a repeater control with grid view items. And handle the binding in the Row Data Bound event.

Comment: I generated UserControl and put there the gridview, but when I want use the UserControl to create an instance it ask me if i'm "missing using directive or an assembly reference?". PS: is the first time i'me creating UserControl.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a UserControl to new a gridView

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

and then add the usercontrol to the placeholder.

```
WebUserControl1 gvr = new WebUserControl1();
            myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gvr);
```

Comment: I generate UserControl and put there the gridview, but when I want use the UserControl to create an instance it ask me if i'm "missing using directive or an assembly reference?". PS: is the first time i'me creating UserControl.